# How to get time zone from user request in Spring Weblux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

In non-Reactive spring we can get Time zone from request in that way -

```
RequestContext.getTimeZone(request)
```

Is there any way to get time zone from ServerRequest, using Spring WebFlux ?

Comment: The same class exists `RequestContext` for the reactive stack and also has a `getTimeZone` method. So not sure what you want/need that isn't available already. I suspect you actually mean the `RequestContextUtils` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, I mean RequestContextUtils :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ServerRequest.headers() which return a Headers object, from which you can call the first method passing the "Accept-Language" or "Timezone" header name, and get the timezone.

```
public Mono<String> getTimezone(ServerRequest request) {
    return request.headers().header("Accept-Language").next().map(timezone -> timezone);
}
```